# Graphics glitches on Intel HD Graphics 530

Tags: x11, graphics, intel

What's the cause of these glitches: https://youtu.be/llS6JwZAT74 ?

The horizontal lines appear on screen redraw. They happen most often on Alt-Tab, or switching to desktop (as in the video).

The glitches started to appear only after I've upgraded the Linux kernel from 3.19 to 4.3.3.

The monitor is Dell U2414H @ 1920x1080 @ 60Hz connected via HDMI.

-

```
starfall@nx ~ $ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1912 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

-

```
starfall@nx ~ $ glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Skylake DT  GT2 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.5.9
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_base_instance, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_derivative_control, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, 
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, 
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, GL_ARB_texture_float, 
    GL_ARB_texture_gather, GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, 
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_viewport_array, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_MESA_pack_invert, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, 
    GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.5.9
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, 
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, 
    GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_stencil_texturing, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, GL_MESA_pack_invert, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_blend_square, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_primitive_restart, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, 
    GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

40 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x091 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x092 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x093 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x095 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x096 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x097 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x098 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x099 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x09e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x09f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0a1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a2 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a3 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a5 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a6 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a7 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a9 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0aa 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ab 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ac 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ad 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0ae 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0af 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0b0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0b2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x04e 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

64 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x04f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x050  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x051  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x052  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x053  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x054  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x055 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x056 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x057 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x058 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x059 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05d  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x05e  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x05f 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x060 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x061 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x062 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x063  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x064  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x065  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x066  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x067 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x068 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x069 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x06b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x06d 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x06e 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x06f  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x071  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x073  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x075 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x077 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x079 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07b 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x07f 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x081 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x082 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x083  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x084  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x085  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x086  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x087 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x088 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x089 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08a 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x08b 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08c 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x08d 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08e 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
```

-

```
starfall@nx ~ $ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x576i       50.1  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   720x480i       60.1     60.1  
   640x480        75.0     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

starfall@nx ~ $ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.3
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rosa
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa"
```

-

```
starfall@nx ~ $ uname -a
Linux nx 4.3.3-040303-generic #201512150130 SMP Tue Dec 15 06:32:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo ideapad Flex 14

I had a similar issue after upgrading to Debian testing

```
mautematico@flex:~$ uname -a
Linux flex 4.3.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.3.5-1 (2016-02-06) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

-

I'm testing KDE, and I changed render mode from OpenGL 2.0 to OpenGL 3.1 on kwin options. Now, I think this issue has gone.

```
mautematico@flex:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Lenovo Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

-

```
mautematico@flex:~$ glxinfo
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_swap_control
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, 
    GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_INTEL_swap_event, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control,                                                                                                                           
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,                                                                                                                                  
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_SGI_make_current_read,                                                                                                                                    
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync                                                                                                                                                    
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):                                                                                                                                               
    Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)                                                                                                                                        
    Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile  (0xa16)                                                                                                                                           
    Version: 11.1.2                                                                                                                                                                             
    Accelerated: yes                                                                                                                                                                            
    Video memory: 1536MB                                                                                                                                                                        
    Unified memory: yes                                                                                                                                                                         
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)                                                                                                                                                               
    Max core profile version: 3.3                                                                                                                                                               
    Max compat profile version: 3.0                                                                                                                                                             
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer, GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, GL_ARB_base_instance, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_derivative_control, 
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary, GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, 
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_clock, 
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine, GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_sync, GL_ARB_texture_barrier, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32, 
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range, GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, GL_ARB_texture_storage, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_viewport_array, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, 
    GL_INTEL_performance_query, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_texture_barrier, GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc

OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_AMD_conservative_depth, 
    GL_AMD_draw_buffers_blend, GL_AMD_performance_monitor, 
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax, 
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility, GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, GL_ARB_buffer_storage, 
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object, GL_ARB_clear_texture, GL_ARB_clip_control, 
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, 
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_copy_image, GL_ARB_debug_output, 
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query, GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, 
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query, GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, 
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters, 
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, GL_ARB_shader_clock, 
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store, GL_ARB_shader_image_size, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples, GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, GL_ARB_texture_env_add, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample, GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, 
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_texture_view, GL_ARB_timer_query, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback3, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev, GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, 
    GL_ATI_texture_float, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_point_parameters, 
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_shader_samples_identical, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_subtexture, 
    GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_integer, 
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_INTEL_performance_query, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_MESA_window_pos, 
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_primitive_restart, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays

OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.1.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
    GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3, GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5, 
    GL_APPLE_texture_max_level, GL_EXT_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_color_buffer_float, 
    GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer, GL_EXT_draw_buffers, 
    GL_EXT_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_EXT_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_read_format_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, 
    GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, GL_EXT_texture_rg, 
    GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, GL_EXT_unpack_subimage, 
    GL_INTEL_performance_query, GL_KHR_context_flush_control, GL_KHR_debug, 
    GL_NV_draw_buffers, GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_read_buffer, 
    GL_NV_read_depth, GL_NV_read_depth_stencil, GL_NV_read_stencil, 
    GL_OES_EGL_image, GL_OES_EGL_image_external, GL_OES_EGL_sync, 
    GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture, GL_OES_depth24, GL_OES_depth_texture, 
    GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map, GL_OES_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
    GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer, GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_stencil8, 
    GL_OES_surfaceless_context, GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot, 
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object

40 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x020 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x021 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ad 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0af 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b0 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b1 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b2 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b3 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0b5 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0b6 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0b7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0b8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0b9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ba 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0bb 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0bc 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0bd 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0be 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0bf 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c0 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c1 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c2 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c3 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c4 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c5 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x0c8 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0c9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0ca 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0cb 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0cc 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0cd 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0ce 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0cf 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0d0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0d1 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x06c 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None

64 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x06d  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06e  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x06f  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x070  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x071  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x072  0 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x073 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x074 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x075 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x077 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x079 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07b  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07c  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x07d 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x07f 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x080 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x081  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x082  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x083  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x084  0 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x085 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x086 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x087 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x088 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x089 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08a 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x08b 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x08c 24 tc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x08d  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08e  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x08f  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x090  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x091  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x092  0 dc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x093 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x094 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x095 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x096 24 dc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x097 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x098 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x099 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09a 24 dc  0  24  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09b  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09c  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x09d 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x09e 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Slow
0x09f 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  0 0 None
0x0a0 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8 16 16 16  0  0 0 Slow
0x0a1  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a2  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0a3  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a4  0 dc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  0 16  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0a5 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a6 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0a7 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0a8 24 dc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0a9 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0aa 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
0x0ab 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  4 1 None
0x0ac 24 dc  0  24  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  0 24  8  0  0  0  0  8 1 None
```

-

```
mautematico@flex:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768      60.10*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   680x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

-

Comment: "OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.1.2" - it looks like you're using OpenGL 3.3, not 3.1. Is that correct, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @DenisGorbachev you're right. I think I'm using OpenGL 3.3... same as you? :/ Now I'm not sure even if kwin changed OpenGL 2.0 to anything else, or if it's just ignoring that setting.

Comment: interesting... did you change anything else to get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating X.org to **1.18.1** version. You will need to install a backport from a custom PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tigerite/mint-xorg-update
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install xorg-update
```

In my case to make installation of `xorg-update` successful, I had to install some required dependencies separately, specifying version explicitly:

```
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms=5.0.14-dfsg-4
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils=5.0.14-dfsg-4
apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11=5.0.14-dfsg-4
```

**More information:** https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/mint-xorg-update